# Expiry must be minimum 1 second to maximum 7 days in minio server

Tags: java, spring-boot, minio

I use java in my application. I use minio server to for file server. When I upload my file to the minio server, I save the url of the same file in the database. But after 7 days the same url is not working. I am using project in localhost and minio server free. I don't want to end the expiration date as 7 days. I want to show for life.

```
public Boolean uploadFile(List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, 
Product product) {
    LinkedList<AppFile> appFiles = new LinkedList<>();
    multipartFiles.forEach(multipartFile -> {

        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        String ext = FileNameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
        AppFile appFile = new AppFile();
        appFile.setName(fileName);
        appFile.setExt(ext);
        appFile.setDateCreated(new Date());
        appFile.setUserId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        appFile.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());  

        try {
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            // save minio server
            minioClient.putObject(PutObjectArgs.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .object(uuid + "-" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename())
                    .stream(multipartFile.getInputStream(), multipartFile.getSize(), -1)
                    .contentType(multipartFile.getContentType())
                    .build());

            // file url
            String url = minioClient.getPresignedObjectUrl(GetPresignedObjectUrlArgs.builder()
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .object(uuid + "-" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename())
                    .build());
            appFile.setUrl(url);
            appFile.setProductId(product);
            appFiles.add(appFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FileException(EnumFile.FILE_CAN_NOT_ADDED.getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
        appFileRepository.saveAll(appFiles);
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. You cannot / must not save the presigned url in the database. Instead your application needs to generate a presigned url whenever someone wants to see the image. All you can save in the database is the key / object name.